# Recursively invoke query in SQL ORACLE with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I have the following query where I can pass multiple items (one chosen by the customer):

```
     SELECT si.item "parentItem",
       si1.item "childItem",
       si1.description "child_description",
       si.uom1 "uom",
       bi.quantity "qty",
       si1.item_type "type"
  FROM inv.system_items si,
       wdps.bill_of_materials bom,
       wdps.bom_inventory bi,
       inv.system_items si1
  WHERE     1 = 1
       AND si1.org_id = 2
       AND si.org_id = 2
       AND bom.org_id = 2
       AND si.item_id = bom.item_id
       AND si.org_id = bom.org_id
       AND bom.alternate_bom_designator IS NULL
       AND bom.bill_sequence_id = bi.bill_sequence_id
       AND bi.disable_date IS NULL
       AND bi.component_item_id = si1.item_id
       AND si.item IN ('123456AR')     --> start point(s)
```

that works well expanding the first level, but I need to go deeply inside other ones produced in the output. The db is in read_only and I have limited access on it, but there is a way to recursively call the above query on 'childItem' produced by the output, also taking care that I don't have a starting point (items can be any already in the database)?

Comment: you must search for recursive cte

Comment: look at connect by.  Who cares if it is a "big big company"?

Comment: make a database , generate some data, show what you tried and what you want and then you have asked a good question

Comment: @OldProgrammer did you mean START WITH/CONNECT BY PRIOR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get hierarchical data from Oracle you don't need self join, but [`connect by`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm).

You query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT bi.component_item_id "parentItem",
       si.item,
       si.description "description",
       si.uom1 "uom",
       bi.quantity "qty",
       si.item_type "type"
  FROM inv.system_items si
  join wdps.bill_of_materials bom 
    on (   si.item_id = bom.item_id
       AND si.org_id = bom.org_id
       AND bom.alternate_bom_designator IS NULL)
  join wdps.bom_inventory bi 
    on (   bom.bill_sequence_id = bi.bill_sequence_id
       AND bi.disable_date IS NULL)
  WHERE    si.org_id = 2
  start with si.item = '123456AR'
  connect by prior si.item = bi.component_item_id
```

Here, `prior si.item = bi.component_item_id` means that recursively for every row will be find child row where parent's `bi.component_item_id` equals to child's `si.item`

Also, notice, I've converted your implicit joins to ANSI ones to ease understanding of what is going on.